# Why does this code behave like a closure?

Tags: javascript

As far as I understood, `for` loops in javascript do not create seperate closures. So can someone explain to me why in the following code the array `dogs` is not filled two references to the same objects? Namely `{name: 'lunski', species: 'dog'}`

```
var animals = [
    {name: 'fluffy', species: 'dog'},
    {name: 'miauw', species: 'cat'}, 
    {name: 'lunski', species: 'dog'}
];

var dogs = [];

for(var i = 0, e = animals.length; i<e; i++){
    if ( animals[i].species === 'dog' ){
        dogs.push(animals[i]);
    }
};
```

I would think that both the array elements in `dogs[]` would hold a reference to `animals[2]`, but in fact the array `dogs` will hold both the fluffy object and lunski object.

EDIT: 
So, it almost looks as if a closure is being created (even though I understand that this is not the case). But the question remains, why is `dogs[]` filled with distinctive objects?

Comment: Why do you think closures are involved here? There are no closures in this code. There aren't even any functions in this code.

Comment: pushing `animals[i]` will not create a reference instead the value is pushed

Comment: No closure is involved here as there is no function involved .The length of dogs is 2.

Comment: your code says "if species is dog, add animal to list of dogs". That's precisely what it does. Both fluffy and lunski are dogs.

Comment: To the people saying there are no closures involved (and are being harsh with their downvotes), that's what I suspected as well, hence the topic... I was surprised to see the values correct, but I learned now that `.push()` passed `animals[i]` as values and not references.

Comment: *I  would think that both array elements would hold a reference to animals[i] with i being 2 in this case.* Why would you think that? You are pushing `animals[i]`, so it pushes `animals[i]`, which depends on the **current** value of `i`, not the final value.

Comment: Sounds like you're overly confused about loops and closures and are trying to see problems where there are none.

Comment: `for (...) setTimeout(() => alert(i))` ← *That's* a closure and an example of an easily unexpected result, because it involves asynchronous execution and a function. None of that is an issue in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up concepts. Leaving closures out of this (it is something else entirely), let's look at the question you asked.

> why in the following code the array dogs is not filled two the same
>   objects {name: 'lunski', species: 'dog'}

You are pushing two distinct objects (`animals[0]` and `animals[2)`) into the `dogs` array - they are not references to the `animals` object itself (arrays are objects) but to the objects contained in the individual `animals` elements.

Because this is not a closure The variable `i` is not fixed to the last value it is set to.

**UPDATE**

I believe I finally understand your intended question - here is an answer showing how an anonymous function with closure and an anonymous function without closure works with your array (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/71d1bgo1/) to test).

The code / fiddle creates 4 inputs. The first and third are without closure and the second and fourth are with closure. The inputs are meant to be clicked on (they have a `click` listener) and they each log `animals[i]` to the console. See the comments in the example below to explain the values logged.

```
var animals = [
    {name: 'fluffy', species: 'dog'}, 
  {name: 'miauw', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'lunski', species: 'dog'}
  ];

var dogs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  if (animals[i].species === 'dog') {
    // the first and third elements created in the loop have no closure
    // the variable i will be set to 2 because it has reached the end of its loop - it's value was not bound with function
    // therefore when you click on the input labeled "fluffy (no closure)" or lunski (no closure) they will log "undefined" to the console since animals[2] is undefined.
        e = document.createElement("input");
        e.value = animals[i].name + " (no closure)" ;
        e.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(animals[i])}
        )
    document.body.appendChild(e);


    // the second and fourth elements created in the loop have closure
    // because the function is enclosed within a function
    // the variable i will be valid and set to what it is when the funtion runs 
    // Note: The exclamation point causes the outer function to be executed immediately - creating the event listener
    // therefore when you click on the input labeled "fluffy (closure)" or lunski (closure)
    // you will see the whole object in the console
    e = document.createElement("input");
    e.value = animals[i].name + " (with closure)" ;;
    !function(animals, i){
        e.addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log(animals[i])}
        )
     }(animals, i)
    document.body.appendChild(e);
  }
};
```

I hope this helps. If you are interested in seeing more examples of closures, look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Can you come up with some example?

Comment: @suyesh - Example for what? closure?

Comment: @suyesh - If you are interested in learning about closures, see the bottom of my post - I have put in a link.

Comment: Ah, it passes a value, not a reference. That answers my question! Then indeed it will not create a closure, which makes sense

Comment: @sjbuysse - Even if you assigned an object to an element and were therefore sharing a reference to that object, this would not be a closure. See the referenced SO post for more info on closures.

Comment: *You are pushing a string into the `dogs` array.* No, he is not. He is pushing an animal object into the `dogs` array.

Comment: @mseifert , since we're pushing objects (and not strings) into the `dogs` array, shouldn't they be passed by reference? I understand it's not a closure, but why does it "behave" like one. And with that I mean, why does `animals[i]` refer to the distinctive objects and not just to `animals[2]`?

Comment: @torazaburo - You are correct. `dogs` will be an array of individual animal objects - which share in common a reference with the `animals` array. I will update my answer to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @sjbuysse - yes the objects in the dogs array are passed by reference. Any change to an object in the `dogs` array will be reflected in the corresponding animals array element.

Comment: @sjbuysse - I've updated the answer with a detailed code example.

Comment: @mseifert , not only do I now understand why my example had nothing to do with closures, I now also have a way better understanding of how closures work. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this out, this has been amazingly helpful.